# Android Studio failed to resolve com.google.android:play-services:29.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the error:

```
failed to resolve com.google.android:play-services:29.0.0
```

It says to install repository and sync project, but when I click that I get whats in the screenshot. Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

[image]

Comment: v29.0.0 will hopefully release in 2046 current version is 8.4.0

Comment: Your second problem is different than your original problem, so you should probably ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I think the latest version of the google play services is 8.4.0. So 29.0.0 is not valid. Please try to use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Comment: That fixed that problem, but now its saying, what I posted in new screenshot above. Any ideas?

Comment: I think 'YOUR PACKAGE NAME' must be replaced with your real package name.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Use modules of play service like this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
```

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

In your `app/build.gradle, add following line at the end of file

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```